# Torsion in cotangent sheaf of the cusp

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be the cuspidal curve $y^2 = x^3$. This is a singular curve with a unique singularity in the origin. One can easily see this using the Jacobi criterion.

How does one show explicitly that the cotangent bundle $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ is not a locally free sheaf?

Of course, the stalk at the origin should have torsion, but I can't seem to locate it explicitly.

I've wondered about this for a while. The reason being that I never really understood via an example why a variety is smooth if and only if its cotangent bundle is locally free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module of Kahler differentials is spanned by $dx$ and $dy$, and differentiating the relation $y^2 = x^3$ gives the relation $2y \, dy = 3x^2 \, dx$. Multiplying by $y$ gives

$$2y^2 \, dy = 2x^3 \, dy = 3 x^2 y \, dx$$

from which it follows that $2x \, dy - 3y \, dx$ is torsion, since it is annihilated by multiplication by $x^2$. (Of course then we need to show that this element isn't just zero, which it is away from the origin.)

Comment: Thank you. As another example, if I would take the nodal curve $y^2 = x^3+x^2$, then we get $2y dy = (3x^2+2x)dx$ which gives the relation $2y^2 dy = (3x^2+2x)y dx=2(x^3+x^2)dy$. So here multiplication by $x$ kills $(3x+2)y dx - 2(x^2+x)dy$.  Is this type of argument always going to work? Would it be possible for you to explain the "general" mechanism behind this a bit?

Comment: @Nick: yes, this always works. One way to say it is that the $1$-form $2x \, dy - 3y \, dx$ ought to vanish, and vanishes away from the origin. The reason it doesn't vanish at the origin is that there are too many Zariski tangent vectors at the origin.